# .Net Core Dockerfile - some questions

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile

This is a default Dockerfile generated by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

(1) Why does it use the runtime (aspnet:7.0) and the sdk? The runtime is included in the sdk, isn't it?

(2)
In a first step the csporj file is copied and then dependencies are downloaded:

```
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
```

In a second step

```
COPY . .
```

It copies everything (included the csproj). So theoretically the step COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"] could be skipped, right?

(3) The build could be skipped as well, right?

```
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there are other ways to do it, but you will have much longer build times and your generated docker image will be much larger.

(1) The runtime image is used as `base`, the sdk image is used as `build`. The final image is based on `base`. This is done to keep the image more compact.

(2) The assumption is that your `.csproj` file does not change that often. With the setup as given, the (time consuming) restore step is only done, when the .csproj file changes, not every time a source file (coming in with `COPY . .`) has changed.

(3) `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` in the Dockerfile use different output directories (specified with `-o`). Only those files in the output directory of the publish step (`/app/publish`) make it into the final image, i.e. in general only the final assembly.